# Android MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE and Intent.ACTION_PICK

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-gallery

Im interested to know if the following android intents are available on every device or are they available only on some devices as `com.android.camera.action.crop` is?

Intent for picking an image from gallery:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

Intent for taking a picture from built-in camera:

```
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that any Android device supports any particular `Intent` structure for any particular user. For example, with restricted profiles on Android 4.3+ tablets, even devices that have a camera app may not support `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` for a particular profile, because it is not allowed by the device owner.

You can use `PackageManager` and `resolveActivity()` to see if the device supports a particular `Intent` for `startActivityForResult()` for the current user. Or, you can catch the `ActivityNotFoundException` that will be raised.

Beyond that, *most* devices for *most* users should support the `ACTION_PICK` `Intent` (or, better yet, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`). Somewhat fewer devices will support `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, simply because not all devices have a camera.

Comment: For my purposes i assume no restrictions by the owner are in effect and that the device has a camera. My doubt is raised for the sake of TouchWizard, HTC Sense etc. So then, i should rephrase: will these intents be available on devices with TW, HTC Sence etc.?

Comment: @Sinisa: They should. Beyond that, you would have to ask HTC.

Comment: Ok, thank you, i was just reading a lot about those custom UIs misbehaving :)

Comment: @Sinisa: I said they exist. I didn't say that they will necessarily behave well. :-) Unfortunately, device manufacturers have a tendency to ignore some of these sorts of `Intents` and not test them all that thoroughly. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, in particular, is bad enough that I've been writing the CWAC-Camera library to make it easier to use the camera directly.

Comment: I just tested my app on Xperia device with miserable result in respect to `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. I will look into CWAC-Camera, because i'm giving up on "built in" intents, and will include everything in code. Thank you for taking interest :)